# How do I fix Windows 7 rotating wallpaper?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization

On my desktop with Windows 7 Professional x64, I have a folder of images that I use for my theme.  Under Personalization (right click on desktop -> Personalize) it is the only theme under 'My Themes'.  Repeatedly, I have noticed the background has stopped rotating and is stuck on one image.  When I go to Personalization, I notice a new theme has been created called 'Unsaved Theme' with one image from my folder and is the current theme.

To fix this, I set the theme back to my folder and delete the single image theme.  How can I prevent this from reoccurring as it has happened multiple times?

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this behaviour where BGInfo is installed on a Windows 7 system.

BGInfo does not support the rotating desktop pictures. This is because each time you log on it makes a copy of your current theme (background, colours, font sizes etc.) and applies the customisations in the BGInfo configuration. The unsaved theme you are seeing is created in this process.

If you have text automatically written on your desktop picture it's safe to say your system administrator is using BGinfo in your enviroment. In this case I suggest you speak with them.

[image]

More information on BGinfo can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897557)

Comment: Thanks, but I am the admin.  This is not installed.

Comment: Well you need to check what else is running on the system. Either you have some strange profile / settings modification software installed (like 7Plus) or you've managed to make some strange non-standard change which has resulted in this fault. Hey, you're the admin. Wide and reload a refresh image. Easy fix :p

Answer (score 2):

I know you said PC (sorry if you think I didn't read the question!). On Laptops in the power options, if it is set on power saver the laptop will stop rotating the image when the laptop is unplugged from the wall. This may or may not apply to you. Just thought it was worth a shot :).

Comment: I edited the question to specify that it is a desktop.

Answer (score 1):

If you make changes to any theme and select "save theme" it does not overwrite the old theme but creates a new one called... "Unsaved Theme". Weird. Is it possible that you are inadvertently creating this yourself?

Comment: Not in any way that I can replicate. I can cycle through the images in my theme by right clicking on the desktop and selecting 'next desktop background'.  After doing this, I checked Personalization and do not see the unsaved theme.